# Скажите, в чем разница между двумя интерпретациями обратного вызова

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, парсер

Вариант 1

```js
window.urlSite=$(this).attr('href');
b1 = $.ajax($(this).attr('href'));
b1.done(function (d1) {
    analysisSite(d1,mask2,window.urlSite);
});
```

Вариант 2

```js
b2 = $(this).attr('href');
b1 = $.ajax($(this).attr('href'));
$.when( b1, b2 ).done(function ( d1, d2 ) {
    analysisSite(d1,mask2,d2);
});
```

в первом происходит работа функции analysisSite() штатно. Во втором - алерт говорит, что страница получена. Но дальше с ней почему-то работать код не хочет.

Второй вариант мне нужен, чтобы помимо запрашиваемой страницы передать и ссылку на эту страницу. Первый вариант не передает данную информацию.

Comment: чем в данном случае является `this`? Вызовы отличаются: в первом случае передается `window.urlSite`, во-втором, `$(this).attr('href')`, если данные значения не совпадают, не удивительно, что они работают по разному. Конкретнее можно сказать только увидев как это все вызывается, и что находится внутри `analysisSite`

Comment: @Grundy,прошу прощения пропустил.Код вопроса дополнил. window.urlSite в 1 варианте тот же $(this).attr('href'); This это то что дает нам функция $(data).find("h3").each(function(){ это часть функции analysisSite() то есть analysisSite() сам себя вызывает пока не найдет то что ищет либо не закончится дерево ссылок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что передается в функцию `done`.

В случае вызова [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) с одним аргументом, параметрами коллбэка `done` будут результаты обещания переданного в `$.when`.

Например:

```
$.when( $.ajax(...) ).done(function ( result, status, xhr) { ... } );
```

В случае же, если параметров несколько:

```
$.when( $.ajax(...), var1, var2 )
```

каждый параметр коллбэка будет соответствовать результату конкретного обещания:

```
$.when( $.ajax(...), var1, var2 ).done(function(res1, res2, res3){
    // res1 - массив из трех элементов `[result, status, xhr]` - результат выполнения `ajax`.
    // res2 - результат выполнения var1
    // res3 - результат выполнения var2
});
```

Так как в твое случае, вторым параметром передается строка, то она же и будет результатом.

В итоге, для того, чтобы получить оба результата, нужно сделать так:

```
$.when( b1, b2 ).done(function ( d1, d2 ) {
    var ajaxResult = d1[0];
    var stringResult = d2;
    analysisSite(ajaxResult, mask2, stringResult);
});
```

Comment: ЕЕСС!!!))) Заработало! Сколько я танцевал вокруг этого) Благодарность огромна моя вам!)) Да но в моем случае лучше обойтись без объявления var переменных а сразу закидывать d1[0] и d2 в функцию.

Comment: @Михаил, я выделил переменные, чтобы наглядно было видно, что откуда мы берем. Стоит, кстати, над именами поработать, а то потом будешь долго вспоминать, что это за b1, а что за d2 :-)

Comment: Я без претензии!) Все правильно, Примногоблагодарен!)